# Android platfrom-tools on M1 macs

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, apple-m1

On my mac M1 I have installed Android Studio Arctic Fox 2020.3.1. It runs natively on my cpu, as well as the ARM64 emulators that came with it. Problem is that it seems to me that I need to install rosetta 2 to run `platorm-tools` such as `adb`. Am I correct? Is there a M1 build of platform tools?

Answer (score 2):

I checked it, even the latest Canary build downloads x64 `adb`:

```sh
file ./platform-tools/adb 
./platform-tools/adb: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
```

Answer (score 1):

> I need to install rosetta 2 to run platorm-tools such as adb

Yes. afaik there is no specific build of platform-tools for darwin-aarch64 offered by google.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to install android studio natively as well, **though I did have to install the canary build** part of the way through in order to get the SDK tools installed (then I was able to just uninstall the canary build and Arctic Fox runs fine now). You can see in the screenshot here - running arm64 and adb in the same terminal.

Best of luck to you!

[arch-arm64_adb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHK5X.png)

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you installed / the steps to achieve that screenshot?